# Google Sheets: select top N cases within groups using QUERY

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I want to make a report: "select salesmen who have N recent Status codes = 2,3,4,5".

A structural example of my data has 35 rows (including 1 header row):
[link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OhxQntxLLzlwZrNZtn7VoF62c7Bvjk0-1cvWa-WkUcA/edit?usp=sharing).
This file has a *Date*, *Sales code* (id of a salesman), *Status code* (id of how successful a transaction was) and other fields which are not necessary for the purpose.

I ended up using three formulas:

1. a `QUERY` function with `IMPORTRANGE`.
   In the example data it is slightly simpler - take only Sales Codes, Status Code, and Date from another sheet, then order by Date, Sales Code. Formula in A9:
   `=QUERY({Source!D1:E, Source!A1:A}, $B$4, 1)`
2. an additional column with a sequentional numbering. Formula in D10:
   `=ArrayFormula(if(len(A10:A), ROW(A10:A) - MATCH(A10:A,A10:A,0) - 8, ))`
3. a QUERY function to extract only N cases (let's say 5). Formula in F9:
   `=QUERY(A9:D, "select A, B where D <="&B3, 1)`

Is there a way to combine all 3 steps into one so I get the output like in F10:G24 using one (and hopefully fast :)) formula? The formula I tried (expanded for readability):

```
=QUERY(
    {
      QUERY({Source!D1:E, Source!A1:A}, $B$4, 1),
      ArrayFormula(
         IF(len(J10:J),
            ROW(J10:J) - MATCH(J10:J, J10:J, 0) - 8,
         )
      )
    },
    "select Col1, Col2 where Col4 <="&B3,
    1
)
```

It gives me the error:

> "Function ARRAY_ROW parameter 2 has mismatched row size. Expected: 28. Actual: 991."

I also tried finite data ranges in `ROW()` and `MATCH()` but that yields an empty table.
In the original database there are ~3500 rows and they will expand, so I think I should stick to infinite ranges to automate data extraction.

Comment: Can we assume that the original data is sorted by sales code i.e. all of a particular salesman's sales are together?

Comment: @TomSharpe, in the original data all the sales are added daily with the latest information entered at the top of the database. No sorting applied. So on any day, there can be any salesman with any sales status.

Comment: I think it is do-able but will have to repeat sort - will post something a bit later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm well it's a bit of a nightmare TBH - a similar question has cropped up before but no easy answer. Here is a draft which involves repeating the basic query several times-

```
=ArrayFormula(query({query(A2:E,"select * where E>=2 and E<=5  order by D, A desc"),
row(indirect("2:"&count(filter(E2:E,E2:E>=2,E2:E<=5))+1))-
match(query(A2:E,"select D where E>=2 and E<=5  order by D, A desc"),
query(A2:E,"select D where E>=2 and E<=5  order by D, A desc"),0)
},"select * where Col6<=5"))
```

But needs looking at more to see if it can be simplified.

This is the full-column version including headers - I think it's OK

```
=ArrayFormula(query({query(A:E,"select * where E>=2 and E<=5  order by D, A desc"),
row(indirect("1:"&count(filter(E:E,E:E>=2,E:E<=5))+1))+1-
match(query(A:E,"select D where E>=2 and E<=5  order by D, A desc"),
query(A:E,"select D where E>=2 and E<=5  order by D, A desc"),0)
},"select * where Col6<=5"))
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! Thank you! It's working! 
Will implement this logic on the large dataset using `IMPORTRANGE`.