# Google Query Language for sum of result using cell reference in query

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

Hello and thanks for your help. I'm new to GQL but have good SQL experence and think I may be missing something small. 
I have 2 sheets i'm working with

```
Main sheet

Colum G
InstanceID
i-554532f4693fc6186
i-09554fcda5f2f3262
i-0047551ae514412d5
```

-

```
Data Sheet

Colum A                 Colum B
i-554532f4693fc6186      10.12
i-554532f4693fc6186      12.12
i-554532f4693fc6186      13.12
i-554532f4693fc6186      17.12
i-554532f4693fc6186      30.12
```

I am trying to write a query that will find all the rows that match the Instance ID in column G against the datasheet Column A and return the AVG of all the matches in column B, the top 5 max, and top 5 min.

I'm finding that I can't point the query to a cell for referencing the instance ID. Is there a way?
I'm using this to try to get the max and it works for 1 but I ned the top 5 or any number.

```
=sort(query('HeC-Metrics'!A:B,"select max(B) Where A = 'i-044532f4693fc6186'"))
```

I'm OK needing to do different queries for each of the required results, AVG, min, max. I would also like to reference the cell in the G column so I don't have to manually enter the InstanceID.

Thanks your time.
Stephen

Comment: Any errors popping up? Not sure why you're trying to wrap a `QUERY` with `SORT` when you can use `order by` in your query statement.

Comment: Also, is this question useful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23427421/query-syntax-using-cell-reference ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it's just a case of getting the right syntax to use a cell value as a match in the query

```
=query(Sheet2!A:B,"select avg(B) where A='"&G2&"' group by A label avg(B)  ''",1)
```

Note that you don't really need the group by if you already have a list of distinct ID's to compare against, but you can't have an aggregate like avg without it.

To get the bottom 5, you can use filter & sortn

```
=transpose(sortn(filter(Sheet2!B:B,Sheet2!A:A=G2),5))
```

(I have transposed the result to get it in a row (row 2) instead of a column)

or you could use a query

```
=transpose(query(Sheet2!A:B,"select B where A='"&G2&"' order by B  limit 5 label B '' ",1))
```

Similarly to get the top 5 you could use

```
=transpose(sortn(filter(Sheet2!B:B,Sheet2!A:A=G2),5,,1,false))
```

or

```
=transpose(query(Sheet2!A:B,"select B where A='"&G2&"' order by B desc limit 5 label B '' ",1))
```

This begs the question of whether you could get these results (a) without needing a list of distinct values and (b) in a single array formula without copying down.

You could certainly get the distinct ID's and averages straight away from a query. Getting the top or bottom n values from a number of groups is much more difficult. I have attempted it in a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51582617/google-sheets-select-top-n-cases-within-groups-using-query/51584696#51584696), but it requires a long and unwieldy formula.

Comment: This worked out great. Any chance you know how to get a query to report  back 2 standard deviations from the mean? I'm trying this.
=query('Sheet2'!A:B,"select (mean(B)+(2*stdev(B))) where A='"&G2&"' group by A label (max(B)+(2*stdev(B))) ''",1)

Comment: Well you only have the basic aggregate functions avg count max min and sum in a query, so it looks as if you'd have to go for a filter/stdev and filter/average combo, maybe using helper cells to make it easier, and just use the results.